# SimpleXml foreach : ignore element

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

```
        <?php

    $xml = "<articles>
    <article id=\"18357302\">
    <articleCategories>
    <articleCategory id=\"default\"/>
    <articleCategory id=\"66607\"/>
    </articleCategories>
    </article>
    </articles>";

    $feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    $items = $feed->article;
    foreach ($items as $article) {

    //  $categorie = $article->articleCategories->articleCategory[id];
    $categories = $article->articleCategories;
    print_r($categories);
    echo "<br>print_r indeed returns an array, but impossible to echo it using foreach!!!<br>";
    foreach ($categories->id as $category) {
if ($category != "default") {
        echo $category;
}
    }
    }
    ?>
```

not sure what i am doing wrong, i am just trying to find a way to remove the part with the default value inside articlesCategories

```
<articleCategory id=\"default\"/>
```

The script needs to ignore this part and just use the next articleCategory from the XML file, and i would prefer to avoid removing it with regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script iterates over `articleCategories` tag.
But it needs to iterate over `articleCategory` tag.

The following changes will be enough.

```
foreach ($categories->articleCategory as $category) {
    if ($category["id"] != "default") {
        echo $category["id"];
    }
}
```